# Is node js a good fit for consuming a slow api?

Tags: node.js

I need to make requests to an api via soap but this api can be very slow. (Sometimes 30 seconds for a response). I basically would like to make the request and then get a response, some time later, without blocking. I would then cache this result.

I do not know node.js very well and was wondering if it would be a good fit for this. Does it support this non blocking http request and response? Does it depend on the library that I am using to make the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all I/O operations in node.js are non blocking. It's general design priciple of node.js.

Node.js already comes with [API](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) to make http requests..

Comment: thanks. I see that it does then depend entirely on the library that is used supporting node js. Luckily for me the client I wanted to use was just updated for it.